# req.on is not getting trigger while using type application/json

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, parsing

```
  req.on("data", (chunk) => {
  console.log("daataa second",body)
  body += chunk.toString();
});
```

When i am posting the data from the postman as the type then it successfully processing the data but when i am passing the data in json format then it is not triggering this method.

If i use json middleware, then none of the data or end event on request object is fired but I removed the json parser from your code, and then the events started firing

Answer (score 0):

JSON parser middleware reads the entire request stream containing a JSON payload, parses it and creates a JavaScript object for you. For  example in Express, [express.json](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#express.json) returns middleware that reads and saves JSON payloads as the `req.body` object if the request contains JSON data

JSON middleware needs to read the entire request stream in order to parse its content using `JSON.parse(string)`, and so will not call `next` to invoke further steps in request routing before the stream has been read and parsed. Hence listeners added later in the route to monitor `data` and/or `end` events will not fire because the data has already been read, and the `end` event has already fired.

Comment: Actually, i have used the express.json but i am getting empty object in the body while triggering the api from sns but when i am req.on then i am able to get the data 
why it is happening?

Comment: The JSON middleware is looking for requests with a `content-type` header set to `"application/json"`, unless it was set to something else in the options object passed to `express.json(options)` to get the middleware. See the link in the question for documentation. Suggest checking what "sns" is sending. If you need more help please _edit the question_ with more specific details of what goes wrong and when.